# Git tagging help - how can I checkout highest minor version tag e.g 1.x and can I pull a tag?

Tags: git, tags, git-tag

I'm attempting to organise our repos a bit better and I thought that it would be a good idea to tag releases but I'm a little confused as to how this is supposed to work.

Ideally what i would like is to be able to tag minor releases as we go through, e.g. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 but then I would like to be able to checkout 1.x and have it automatically resolve to the latest tag in 1.x release - is this possible?

Secondly I have a couple of projects which are updated from another repo. For example, we have skinned product versions under individual repos, and then we have a repo which contains a whitelabel version of the product where we carry out all fundamental code changes/fixes.

Typical workflow would be to fix an issue in the whitelabel repo, then pull the whitelabel fixes into individual projects using a second remote, but how would I pull a specific tag from this additional remote when the tags dont seem to work with git pull commands.

I'm in the early stages of implementing this, so if this is fundamentally the wrong approach then please enlighten me before I travel too far down the path.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hi! I use this standard for manage my repository http://semver.org/ support minor, patch and major release is complete for me.. Command for pull a tag is $. git pull --tags

Comment: I will probably go with semantic versioning providing I can work out how to pull releases out in the way I would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question: you can't have git to that automatically. You can however, manually update a 1.x branch or tag that points to the same commit as the latest 1.x release, but that is a business rule that you will have to enforce.

For the second question: you have to specified to git pull (and push) that you want them to operate on tags.

Comment: I know I can do git pull --tags but what I would need to do is to pull in a specific tagged commit. something like git pull origin 1.1, is something like this possible?

Comment: yes. and if you use `--depth 1`, it'll pull just that commit.